# Erlang: Mixing lists:seq with pattern matching

Tags: erlang

I need your help again. I was wondering if it is possible to use lists:seq(from,to) within pattern matching? Below is the code that I am trying to achieve

```
product_selling_price_evaluate(lists:seq(1100,1190),standard_produce,Costprice) -> Costprice*10;
product_selling_price_evaluate(lists:seq(1200,1300),standard_produce,Costprice) -> Costprice*20;
product_selling_price_evaluate(lists:seq(1400,1500),standard_produce,Costprice) -> Costprice*30;
product_selling_price_evaluate(lists:seq(1600,1700),standard_produce,Costprice) -> 40*Costprice.
```

When I compile the code it gives me a illegal pattern error!

Example input would be

```
selling_price:product_selling_price_evaluate(1100,standard_produce,10).
```

and I want it to find the first one as a match and give the output as

```
100
```

Will lists:seq work with case?

Let me explain in a more simple way. I have the below cases

```
1100 to 1190   = Apples
1200 to 1300   = Oranges
1400 to 1500   = Bananas
1600 to 1700   = Berries
```

if I give the input as 1125 I want the output to be Apples. Again if I give the input as 1450, I want the output to be Bananas. I hope u guys understood, what am I trying to achieve!

Comment: You surely don't want to match against a list with hundred element. And your example means exactly that. But you seem to need membership of argument in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I interpret right what you are trying to achieve,  what you probably are looking for are guards.

Something like this (untested):

```
product_selling_price_evaluate(N,standard_produce,Costprice) when N >= 10 andalso N <= 20 -> Costprice*10; 
product_selling_price_evaluate(N,standard_produce,Costprice) when N >= 21 andalso N <= 30 -> Costprice*20;
[...]
```

Comment: I guess, the solution you suggested is the way forward! thanks!

Comment: Okay, I get a syntax error when I used "andalso". Am I missing something? `product_selling_price_evaluate(productcode,standard_produce,Costprice) when productcode >= 1100 andalso productcode <= 1199 -> Costprice*10;`

Comment: Okay, sorted out it should `product_selling_price_evaluate(Productcode,standard_produce,Costprice) when Productcode >=1100, Productcode =< 1199 -> Costprice + Costprice*0.40;`

Answer (score 1):

You're not giving the desired input, your function is expecting a list([11001,1101, 1102,...,1189,1190]) as its first argument, where as you're giving a number i.e. 1100.

Comment: Oh,then I shouldn't be using lists:seq there! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Guards can be comma-separated (,), it has the same meaning same as `andalso`.

```
product_selling_price_evaluate(N,standard_produce,Costprice)
    when 10 =< N, N =< 20 -> Costprice*10; 
product_selling_price_evaluate(N,standard_produce,Costprice)
    when 21 =< N, N =< 30 -> Costprice*20;
...
```

`<=` is illegal here, use `=<` instead.

Comment: Oh, what is said is right, I eventually found it! thanks though!